# What it needs to have a server?

Tags: apache-2.2, server-setup

Well this is fairly a basic question. Lets say I want to operate a website from my own personal computer. Its a pretty easy task by port forwarding port 80 and starting my Apahe server.

Why this is not practical is because, serve so many people with my slow Internet connection! So how does web hosting servers solve this problem? How are they able to serve so many people?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How are they able to serve so many people?

Well....

> Well this is fairly a basic question

Hm, I hate to say it, but it is not a too SMART question.

See,

this is like asking "ok, I have a car, but when I want to transport many many more people it is too small, how to large companies do that" - by NOT USING A CAR.

Similar, web hoster DO NOT USE A SLOW HOME CONNECTION.

Is that not OBVIOUS?

They have data centers and connectivity there is not handled in "I have a DSL connection" but "I Have backhaul connections that may be many many 10gigabit connection". Simple like that.

They use more bandwidth.

In the data center my servers currently are they have more than 110 gigabit link capacity.

Funny you have to ask- you don't ask about te3chnology, but ask about how they do it when a normal home connection is too slow.

Comment: I didnt downvoted, and I didnt put my question upto the point. I was more like intrested in how they get high speed connection? and is it practical to have your own computer as a server?

Comment: Well, THEY can do the same as you - just call any decent provider and he will GLADLY deliver you 1 gigabit to your door. THe price may shock you. Is it practical? Depends. I run a lot of own servers, some at home. It all depends WHAT YOU USE THEM FOR.

Comment: TomTom, you may have a lot of points, but try to show class too.  There is no reason to belittle the guy, insult him, or use caps.  Simply suggest that his question is better suited for SuperUser.com or he should do some research first.